# Tranfer magento site

Tags: localhost, transfer

hello guys is there a way to transfer magento site from my local PC localhost to another PC in localhost ?

I want to transfer it from my PC to my laptop.

thanks inadvance

From windows 10 to windows 8

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to use source control, like [git](https://github.com) or another version control platform. That way you can push your code to it and then the other machine can pull the code down. Then you can both work on the same project and push code to the same place to have a single source of truth.

Failing that, you could zip/tarball is all up and then pass the archive on a removal media like usb/dvd/floppy disk.

`tar -zcvf archive-name.tar.gz directory-name`

Comment: i use it on windows 10 and want to trasnfer it to laptop using windows 8
will this work ?

Comment: Yes should make no difference, should only cause an issue if you were going from windows to linux/macOS or vis versa